# Grails httpconnection to self-signed cert

Tags: grails, ssl, httpconnection

I have this method to post using httpconnection. I'm getting error sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target when I connect to self-signed website. How do I ignore the cert?

```
def post(url, jsonData){
    url = new URL(url)
    def connection = url.openConnection()
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST")
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    connection.doOutput = true
    def writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.outputStream)
    writer.write(jsonData)
    writer.flush()
    writer.close()
    connection.connect()
    def resp = connection.content.text
    resp
}
```